# I will write an eprom driver.This writing process will be based on address and size.Iwill write it in Clanguage

Tags: struct, function-pointers, spi, eeprom

I have an eeprom that communicates via SPI. I will write a driver for this eeprom, but this writing process will not contain any ready-made functions. Writing and reading operations will start from a certain address and write this much data. I write in c language. It will be valid for embedded systems. What kind of structure and algorithm can I create?

I created a struct structure and this structure has two members, address and size. How can I assign these two members as parameters to the writing function and how can I perform writing operations in the body of the function? Please help me.I plan to do it using function pointer

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. There are already algorithms and data structures for this purpose, implemented in any SPI library: if you have a good reason to avoid using an existing library, you should already know what you want your system to look like.

Comment: So: why does the process need to avoid ready-made functions?

Comment: I have not seen a ready-made function that does this. I want it to be written as bam bam one under the other according to the address and size value.

Comment: So you want to send the contents of a buffer over SPI?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I will develop a driver to write data to my EEPROM using the SPI protocol. I want it to write this by address and size. Write this amount of data starting from the specified address. Or I want to create a function that writes data of this size to the following address range

Comment: If you have an example of this, share it with me

Comment: There is already number if drivers for the EEPROM chips. Are you sure you need a brand new driver? If so, why?